# React Native Is there a way to convert a base64 BACK to a uri?

Tags: react-native

In my React Native app I need to convert some base64 images back to uri. Reason being that uris are temporary and can be deleted from the cache. There are a lot of ways of converting URIs to base64 but not vice versa. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer) library to decode base64 encoded data in a react native app.

```
npm i buffer
```

Once installed you can import the buffer library into your react native app

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
```

and then decode base64 encoded data

```
Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
```

The line above returns the decoded data as bytes and

```
Buffer.from(data, 'base64').toString('ascii');
```

returns the decoded data as an ascii encoded string.

Comment: oh isee, and you are sure this will work with react native?

Comment: Yes, I verified my answer with react native version 0.65.1 and 0.66